# Confusion when applying Hamming window to signal

Tags: discrete-signals, audio, signal-analysis, c

I am writing some code which takes a signal of length $n$, and processes it in 20 ms chunks with 5 ms of overlap...  So basically I have a buffer of 20 ms worth of sampled data, and I am trying to apply a Hamming window to it. For some reason, when I listen back to the audio generated from this, I am getting nothing-- and the output of my Hamming window seems to be pretty static-- values that are all somewhere near 0.07999999989377744. I am wondering, what am I doing wrong in my calculations?

So, assuming `s[n]` is my 20 ms sample buffer, this is the code I'm running:

```
sampleRate = 44100;
frames     = (sampleRate / 1000) * 20;  // 20 ms

for (i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
    hammingWindowValue = (0.54 - 0.46) * Math.cos((2 * PI * s[i]) / frames));
    s[i] = hammingWindowValue;
}
```

Comment: why in the world did someone down vote this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not applying the Hamming window correctly. You should first calculate the Hamming window values, with something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
    hammingWindowsValue[i] = 0.54 - 0.46 * Math.cos(2*PI*i / (frames-1) );
}
```

(Note the lack of parenthesis around (0.54-0.46)). Then, you should multiply your signal by the window values:

```
for (i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
    s[i] = hammingWindowValue[i] * s[i];
}
```

(Of course, in practice that code can be simplified. I separated it into two loops to make it conceptually clearer.)

In brief: when windowing a signal, you first calculate the window samples, and then multiply the window and your signal.

Comment: @patrick, you're welcome, I'm glad it helped.

Comment: doesn't look like neither question nor answer are popular.  :-\

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: unexplained downvotes is one of the big negatives about this site for me... makes me want to quit sometimes.